# I have 12.04 but I cannot get updates

Tags: 12.04, updates

The text `Do you want to start the upgrade?` appears, but there is no place to press YES.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal (CTRL+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

if you got this error

"Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock"

1. Open the terminal and run one of these commands:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
   ```

or

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

or

```
sudo killall -9 apt-get aptitude
```

Then make an update with this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```